# Select from both tables with where clause with Rails 5

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have models `User`(users table) and `Job` (jobs table). One user can have many jobs (one to many relation).
User model:

```
has_many :jobs, foreign_key: :user_id
```

Job model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Users table has email column. Jobs table has foreign key `user_id` and column `job_name`.
There is a row in users table with id = 1 and there is a row in jobs table with user_id = 1.

I want to select from both tables rows, where `users.email = some email`.

First I tried with `:includes`, but:

> User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'email@email.com' LIMIT 11
>
> Job Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs` WHERE `identities`.`user_id` = 1
>
> ActiveRecord::Relation [#User id: 1, email: "email@email.com", name: "name",created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>

After that with `:joins`:

```
User.joins(:jobs).where(users: {email: 'email@email.com'})
```

, it returns same, but with one query

> ActiveRecord::Relation [#User id: 1, email: "email@email.com", name: "name",created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>

If I make this :

```
user = User.find(1)
user.jobs
```

I get the result.

How can I get result from both tables where `users.email = some email` with `join` ?

Comment: Instances of what class are you expecting in the result set, `Job` or `User`?

Comment: User, but if can't I just need data from both tables.

Comment: So you want to shove `Job`s' fields into instances of `User`. This is a certain way to break your object-oriented modeling. What's the problem with `user = User.find(1); user.jobs`? When you iterate over `jobs`, you still have `user` in scope and are able to use his data.

Comment: I am using email, but if I do `user = User.where(email: 'some email')` and after that user.jobs, it says `undefined method jobs`

Comment: Well, yes, `User.where(email: 'some email')` is not a single user, but a collection of users (which could possibly contain one user, or none, or many). So you want to get all jobs of users with a particular email (or one user if it's unique)?

Comment: One user with many jobs. `find_by(email:'email'),includes(:jobs)`, returns me this error - `NoMethodError: undefined method `includes' for #<User:0x00000008d96928>`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly what you want is to be able to fetch a user filtered by the email and fetch all the jobs related to the user. If so, the following would work,

```
User.where(email: 'email@email.com').includes(:jobs)
```

This would fetch you the user based on email and eager load the jobs related to the user. Which means you should only includes if you definitely need the jobs listing.

If you use joins then, if there is a user without jobs he won't get listed because joins is converted to an "INNER JOIN" in ActiveRecord.

Comment: It returns what I typed above (Only row from users table), but it makes 2 requests. I don't know why. It is not with join.

Comment: That's how lazy loading works, it executes two queries but, that happens in the same connection. Inner join fetches you the data for the user but, when you do user.jobs then, another request is sent to the database. But, using includes if you call user.jobs then, the server wouldn't make another call to fetch the jobs separately.

Comment: Thx, but still with `:includes` I am getting only users data.

Comment: Are you saying if you use :includes get the user and then, call user.jobs you are getting an empty array? or nil?

Comment: If I assign it to var user and call user.jobs, it says - `undefined method jobs`. I am using Rails console and there I see what is the result and query.

Comment: Ahh I got it. I think you are using User.where(email: 'email@email.com').includes(:jobs), this would return an array of users so, either you have to access as the following,

users = User.where(email: 'email@email.com').includes(:jobs)
users.first

Ideally change your code to the following,

User.find_by(email: 'email@email.com').includes(:jobs)

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method `includes' for #<User:0x00000008d96928>`

Comment: users = User.where(email: 'email@email.com').includes(:jobs)
users.first.jobs

Should work for sure

Comment: Thx, this works, but how to select all jobs for this user?

Comment: Well, it should return you all the jobs of that user by default. How many jobs do you see? and how many jobs are actually there for the user?

Comment: In this way I see the first job. I have two jobs for this user

Comment: The solution is ` user = User.find_by(email: 'email@email.com')` - without `:includes` and `user.jobs`

Comment: But I can't understand why there is no way with joins.